# xlsxwriter - Defining column format based on column name

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

How to define a form for column based on column name in xlsxwriter.

For example when column name is **Sale_Date** I would like to define *date_format* whereas if the column name is **count_of_sales** I would like to use *number_format*

I know how to define a format for a specific column but I am not sure how to define it based on column name as shown below.

```
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss', 'font_size': 14})
worksheet1.write('A1', 'Sale_Date', date_format)
```

Could anyone advice. Thanks..

Update:

```
# create an output stream
output = BytesIO()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')

# Create the workbook
workbook = writer.book
# Create and name the sheets
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Cover Sheet')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sample Data')

# Number formatting
number_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '####', 'font_size': 14})
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss', 'font_size': 14})

for col in field_names:
    worksheet1.write('A1', col, date_format if 'created_at' in col else number_format)

# Defining Cover sheet format
worksheet.set_column('A:BZ', None, color_format)

# # header column
row = 0
col = 0

for data in title:
    worksheet1.write(row, col, data, number_format)
    col += 1

#Pulling monthly data for columns for weekly raw data sheet
current_row = 1

for values in output_file:
    for idx, value in enumerate(values):
        worksheet1.write(current_row, idx, value, number_format)
    current_row += 1

# the writer has done its job
writer.close()

# go back to the beginning of the stream
output.seek(0)

# finally return the file
return output
```

Sample column list:

```
name, age,class,join_date,date_of_birth,filing_date
```

Comment: Have you tried using conditions, something like: `for col in col_names: worksheet1.write('A1', col, date_format if 'date' in col else num_format)`

Comment: @RahulChawla,wodering how could I do if the date column is not fixed and its position keeps changing from column 1 to column 2 and so on..

Comment: One instance of the table will have static positions, right? It can change in other runs.

Comment: @RahulChawla what I meant was how to iterate through columns other than A1.. Believe this would check cell A1 each time.. Reason being the columns are dynamic and hence the date column could be in cell A1 in one run and then G1 in the next run

Comment: @RahulChawla the max number of columns could go upto 30..

Comment: I think now I understand your problem, can you share sample worksheet?

Comment: @RahulChawla, I will included my code, will this help..

Comment: @RahulChawla, I have included some of the columns from my list and the number of columns could vary each time.

Comment: You can read the file using pandas then `data.columns` will give you column list post that use `for` loop like `for i, col in enumerate(col_list): worksheet1.write(1,i+1,col, date_format if 'date' in col else num_format)`